# sql file stream PathName dosent show in window fileExplorer

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

I have a **file Stream** Sample database , I have added records into table.
When I use file.PathName() my sample project in c# **SqlFileStream** class recognize this address and retrieve my file but did not show in windows file Explorer?
What is this address? Is it fake address?This class may look at FileGroup path for finding real address?if not how this class find path?

> \ComputerName\SQL2016\v02-A60EC2F8-2B24-11DF-9CC3-AF2E56D89593\FileStreamTestDB\dbo\BLOB_Table\FileData\00953530-2F65-4AC9-81E9-0281EFB89592\VolumeHint-HarddiskVolume3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in a `FILESTREAM` column are stored inside of the database. You can see the internal files stored in the database by browsing the local file system `FILESTREAM` filegroup directory but that path is not exposed for remote access and shouldn't be used at all. You'll need to use `SqlFileStream` to get a handle for access to `FILESTREAM` data via the Win32 API.

If you want to access files stored in the database via Windows Explorer or any other application, consider using [`Filetable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server) instead. A `FileTable` leverages `FILESTEAM` internally but exposes the files stored in the table via a UNC path for non-transactional access. That allows files to be added/change/deleted via the share just regular files or with T-SQL INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. In both cases, the changes are stored in the database `FileTable` and reflected in the `FileTable` directory share too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream`

Need get  `GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()` for access to file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/access-filestream-data-with-opensqlfilestream?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Please double check the edit and if possible edit the language to clarify what should be done exactly in OP's context.